# Match all words beginning with same pattern except with underscore

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have a list of words like this:

```
raceasian_00
racenonhisp
raceblackpy_5
racewhite_00
racetotalpop
```

I want to `preg_match()` only the words that begin with `race` but do **NOT** contain an underscore.

This pattern selects all words that DO have the underscore:

```
(race).+?(?=_).+
```

And I think the negative lookahead should be involved somehow, but I can't figure out how to add it in.  This didn't work:

```
(race).+(?!_).+
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
\brace[^_\s]*\b
```

- `\b` - assert position at a word boundary
- `race` - match `race` at the beginning of the word literally
- `[^_\s]*` - matches zero or "many" characters except `_` and whitespace `\s`

https://regex101.com/r/E1yHVY/4

Comment: @EatPeanutButter, welcome. We need exclude whitespace because `race asin` will form 2 words, but we need to match only consistent single words